# The friendship of auntie bear

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

There is a phrase in our language that its literal translation to English will be **"The friendship of auntie bear"**. In order to explain when we use this phrase, I will tell you the story behind this phrase:

> A man had a bear friend. One day, while this man was sleeping, a
>   number of flies collected on his face. The bear decided to help his
>   friend by driving them off, so she lifted up a stone of 20 man's weight
>   and threw it to the face of the man in order to kill the fly. The fly
>   escaped, but the man died due to the hit.

So as you see, this phrase is used to refer to a friend that loves you and wants to help you, but he makes serious problems (and even kills you!) by doing stupid things for you. (This is when we say a wise enemy is better than an ignorant friend.)

I'm wondering if there is a word or phrase in English for this kind of friendship.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the part of the USA where lots of Yiddish words have entered into the vernacular (mostly the urban Northeast), then you'll encounter the [schlemiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel).  A schlemiel is a very clumsy or unclever person who generally means well, but causes chaos all around him.

Quoting from the wikipedia article linked above:

> The inept *schlemiel* is often presented alongside the unlucky *schlimazel*. A Yiddish saying explains that "a schlemiel is somebody who often spills his soup and a schlimazel is the person it lands on."

There's no particular connotation of friendship though - a schlemiel is as dangerous to strangers as he is to close associates; although he may cause more damage to the latter just because of frequent proximity.

Comment: Far be it from me to discourage anyone from using Yiddish (generally), but I don't think schlemiel works here.  Yes, a schlemiel's bad luck might hurt a friend he was trying to help, but he might also hurt a friend he wasn't trying to help.  The schlimiel's bad luck is too generalized.  The *khaleh kharshe* (the Persian idiom we're discussing) causes problems only when trying to help.  This character exists in American culture, but I don't think we have a name for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat [similar idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/With+friends+like+that%2C+who+needs+enemies%3F) in English:

> With friends like that, who needs enemies?

However, this idiom is not reserved for good intent. For example it could also apply to a supposed friend who does not act kindly.